# VBA return value from Stored Procedure "has too many arguments specified"

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a stored procedure that returns a value of either 0 or 1, depending on whether the Windows username provided, exists within a table.

I have added the VBA to execute the stored procedure and handle the return value so I can use it as a variable, but the code fails at the `Execute` stage with:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'x01_sl_getUserExists' has too many arguments specified.

The stored procedure simplified here:

```sql
USE [Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure] 
    @windowsAD nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @usrStatus int

    SELECT @usrStatus = COUNT(1) FROM [SYS_Login] as lgn WHERE lgn.[SYS_LoginAD] = @windowsAD;

    RETURN @usrStatus
END
```

VBA code to execute and return here:

```vb
Dim db As ADODB.Connection
Dim pr As ADODB.Parameter
Dim pr2 As ADODB.Parameter
Dim sp2 As ADODB.Command
Dim usrStatus as Integer

Set db = New ADODB.Connection
Set sp2 = New ADODB.Command
Set pr = sp2.CreateParameter("ReturnValue", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
Set pr2 = sp2.CreateParameter("@windowsAD", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, getUserID)

With sp2
    .CommandText = "Procedure"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .ActiveConnection = db
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters.Append pr
    .Parameters.Append pr2
End With

sp2.Execute '// CODE FAILS HERE
usrStatus = sp2.Parameters("@return_value")
```

Essentially I want to get the RETURN value of 0 (user doesn't exists) or 1 (user does exist) so I can assign it to the variable `usrStatus` and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.Parameters.Refresh` [populates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/refresh-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017#parameters) the `Parameters` collection by going to the server and reading the procedure's metadata.

Then you add same parameters manually, ending up with four parameters instead of two.

Either remove the `Refresh`, or do not create the parameters manually.

Comment: Plus, when creating/using the return value parameter call it "ReturnValue" or "@return_value" but not both.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg for the speedy response - that did the trick! I wasn't aware that `Parameters.Refresh` did that; I thought it _cleared_ the parameters. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to add @GSerg - they are both called `@return_value` but I must have amended one of them incorrectly when editing the examples to post here. Thanks!